# Regular expression for a-b, a-c but not a-a?

Tags: regex

I try to find method definitions except constructors. 
To simplify Im looking for **abc::def, foo::bar but not foo::foo**

I already know how to write an expression like so:

```
\w[\w\d_]+::\w[\w\d_]+
```

But how to make sure the left part of the :: does **not** match the right part?

By the way, I cannot check if there is a type definition left of the qualified method name. I have a very old project where it was fine to not specify a type if it was int.

Comment: Which dialect and engine are you using?

Comment: You can use [`\b(\w+)::(?!\b\1\b)\w+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/aV1tL0/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\w` already matches `\d` and `_` and `\w[\w\d_]+` = `\w{2,}`.

You can capture the first "word" (before `::`) and check with a negative lookahead that the "word" after `::` is not equal to it:

```
\b(\w+)::(?!\b\1\b)\w+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV1tL0/1)

Explanation:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more alphanumeric and underscore characters
- `::` - 2 consecutive colons
- `(?!\b\1\b)` -  the next "word" cannot be the same as the value in Group 1
- `\w+\b` - one or more alphanumeric and underscore characters followed with a trailing word boundary.

If you are not looking to match 1-character "words", you can use

```
\b(\w{2,})::(?!\b\1\b)\w{2,}\b
```

Comment: If you want to match `A::B`, use the first regex. If not, use the second one.

Comment: Thank you! The point I was missing is the use of \1 as part of the expression. I've definitvely learned something new today.

Comment: `\1` is a backreference to the *value* stored in the memory buffer #1 (captured with the first capturing group. You may read more about [**backreferences** at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can capture first part and check if it's repeated using back-referencing like this.

**Regex:** `\b(\w[\w\d_]+)::(?!\1)\w[\w\d_]+`

**Explanation:**

- `\b(\w[\w\d_]+)` matches the first part.
- `(?!\1)` negative lookahead for first part. If repeated whole match will be discarded.
- `\w[\w\d_]+` If not repeated then this part will match.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV6sK7/1)

Comment: `[\w\d_]` = `\w`. Also, this won't match [`A::B`](https://regex101.com/r/nX0cZ4/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Tried to keep OP's pattern as it is. Seems like there should be atleast two characters and first one should be from character class `\w`. Should get a clarification on that one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would check both answers as helpful if that was possible. What I liked about yours is the link to the Regex101 Demo.